# change Component name with map function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom

I am trying to change component name.

It is normally like `<Dashboard/> and <Table/>`. But I want to make like

```
const names = [ {"name":Dashboard},{"name":Table}] 
names.map(c => { <c.name />}
```

```
render(){
return(
        {names.map(c => {
          <Panel>
            <Panel.Body>
              <Row>              
                <Col md={4}>
                  <FormControl
                  />
                </Col>
              </Row>
              <hr />
              <c.name bla={bla}  />
              <hr />
            </Panel.Body>
          </Panel>
)}
```

Comment: You aren't returning from your `map` callback for one.

Comment: In the future, you should also clearly explain what problem you're facing. For example: what about the given code is not working? Are you getting an error message? What is happening that you do not expect? This information will help you get better answers.

Comment: and what is the error with this code?

Comment: can you reproduce the problem online in the sandbox?

Comment: You're still not returning from your `map`.. Please include a more complete example ([see here for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)). The one in the question is not syntactically correct, so we can only assume there is more not included.

Comment: I changed my code to previous one. below is not the correct answer I dont know why they gave point to it.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#choosing-the-type-at-runtime), you need to declare a capitalized variable first:

```
import React from 'react';
import { PhotoStory, VideoStory } from './stories';

const components = {
  photo: PhotoStory,
  video: VideoStory
};

function Story(props) {
  // Correct! JSX type can be a capitalized variable.
  const SpecificStory = components[props.storyType];
  return <SpecificStory story={props.story} />;
}
```

and then you can call your component name by using your variable.
And in your case, it would be :

```
{names.map((c) => {
        const CapitalizedComponent = c.name;
        return <CapitalizedComponent />;
      })}
```

Please also notice that the map function in your code didn't return anything.

[working example in sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-noyce-0leh7?file=/src/App.js:221-336)

Comment: didnt work inside the CapitalizedComponent variable I see WrappedComponent: class DashboardTable

Comment: what is the problem exactly? does the sandbox work for you?